# Django rest, запуск стороннего скрипта в бэкграунде

Tags: python, django, unix, django-rest-framework

Имеется сервер на django, который, в ответ на запрос, должен запускать сторонний сервер и возвращать его ip (сторонний сервер далее никак не связан с django).

Для этого я использовал bash скрипт с примерно следующим содержанием 
/pathToServerExecutable serverParams &
И запускал его через os.system (или subprocess)

В итоге запрос выдает connection timeout.

Вопрос: Как правильно запускать такие отдельные процессы?

Comment: А конфигурация вашего стороннего сервера какая? `connection timeout` может свидетельствовать о том, что сервер либо лежит, либо не позволяет обращаться к нему(и выполнять на нем команды). Что вы подразумеваете под `запускать сторонний сервер`? На нем что-то должно выполнится?

Comment: @Klimenkomud сторонний сервер - udp сервер написанный на c#. Он точно запускается, потому что он есть в процессах и к нему можно подключиться. Но запрос в django в это время висит. (Запускать сторонний сервер - просто запускать исполняемый файл в отдельном потоке)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас происходит такая ситуация: `subrocess.call()` ожидает завершения и, соответственно, django также "зависает" на этом моменте и ожидает ответа. В вашем случае запускается сторонний сервер и пока он работает - будет ожидаться ответ.

Пример (вызов этой функции будет ожидать ответа до тех пор, пока вы не закроете firefox или он, к примеру, не "упадёт"):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("firefox")
```

Чтобы этого не происходило, можно, например, запустить процесс в отдельном потоке, для этого в python предусмотрен модуль threading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Пример запуска в отдельном потоке (естественно, можно доработать под свои нужды и передавать не только команду, но также и параметры, обрабатывать ошибки и т.д.):

```
import threading
import subprocess

class RunCommandThread(threading.Thread):
    """
    Класс для запуска команды в отдельном потоке
    """
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(self.command)
```

Использование:

```
RunCommandThread("firefox").start()
```